# Creating a layout using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

The below diagram was given to me in an interview questions and the interviewer told me that I am missing clear:both in my code.

[image]

I tried something like this. But couldn't get the desired results

```css
.name3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90px;
}

.name {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90px;
}

.name1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
}

#name2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="name3">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="name1"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: When writing code in an interview, try to write valid code. Ids can not be repeated, you have 3 divs with the same id ....  This alone will make your interviewer give you a bad evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.name3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.name {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
    width: 99px;
    float: left;
}
.name1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 42px;
    width: 34px;
    float: left;
}
#name2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="name3">
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="name1"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
    <div id="name2"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this with Flexbox.

Here you can learn more: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.top,.side,.square {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.container .main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.container .main .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .main .content .square {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">.top</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="side">.side</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="square">.square</div>
      <div class="square">.square</div>
      <div class="square">.square</div>
      <div class="square">.square</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's part of an interview question and I think they wanted to see the use of floats instead of flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

*Hi SIMIN i have read your question and here is my solution to that. Copy past the code below in your editor. Also note that i was using opera browser for running this code, so if you are using different browser there may be a little difference in output. Good luck*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .name3{
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 53px;
                width: 93px;
                }

            .name{
                  border: 0.5px solid black;
                  height: 10px;
                  width: 92px;
                  float: left;
                }

            .name1{
                  border: 0.5px solid black;
                  height: 41px;
                  width: 30px;
                  float: left;
                  clear: left;
                }

            #name2one{
                height: 20px;
                width: 30px;
                border: 0.5px solid black;
                float: left;
                clear: none;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="name3">
            <div class="name"></div>
            <div class="name1"></div>
            <div id="name2one"></div>
            <div id="name2one"></div>
            <div id="name2one"></div>
            <div id="name2one"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using percentage in width

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper, .header, .sidebar, .article{
   border: 1px solid black;
   float: left;
}
.wrapper {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
.header{
  width: 100%;  
  height: 20px;
}
.sidebar {
   height: 80px;
   width: 33.33%;
}
.article {
    height: 40px;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```